# PromQL Prometheus Query - How do we specify a data with multiple time range in single query / prometheus api

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

From Grafana, I want to display data with prometheus API such that in the same query need to display the data with multiple time range in same query.

Example: This is prometheus API with one time range.
`http://prometheus:9090/api/v1/query?query=pt_analytics_all_api_http_server_transciationLimit&start=now()-24h&end=now()`

Is it possible to add multiple time range in same prometheus API?.

Answer (score 1):

No, [Prometheus' query API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/) doesn't support anything like this.

If you want to see multiple time ranges of the same length in Grafana you can use multiple queries, like this

```
pt_analytics_all_api_http_server_transciationLimit offset 3d
```

changing offset according to your needs.

If you need to do this in API, you can either call API two time with the different queries, similarly to how it's done in Grafana, or use some trickery in query itself to acquire result in one go:

```
pt_analytics_all_api_http_server_transciationLimit * on() group_left(range) absent(non_existent{range="original"})
or pt_analytics_all_api_http_server_transciationLimit offset 3d * on() group_left(range) absent(non_existent{range="3 days before"})
```

If you want to show two separate time ranges in the panel consequentially, something like 00:00-09:00 and right after it 21:00-23:00, that is not possible with Grafana (nor with single call of API)